# Jquery css code is not working in browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my css that I am applying on one td.
But this is not working in IE,FF and other browsers.

```
 $("#tdTopMenu").css({ "backgroundColor": "003f60", "height": "17pt", "display": "block", "white-space": "nowrap", "min-width": "1250px" });
```

Whereas If I write one line

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

then its started showing in IE only not in other browsers.
Please help

Comment: replace "backgroundColor": "003f60" on "background-color":"#003f60"  and will work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`003f60` is not a colour. `#003f60` is. Make sure the CSS you are trying to apply is valid.

Comment: Also backgroundColor should be background-color.

Comment: @mzohreh according to http://api.jquery.com/css/ both notations are viable, `backgroundColor` and `background-color`. The only difference is that you don't need quotations around backgroundColor.

Comment: @mzohreh Not only backgroundColor, other style like `fontWeight, marginLeft, marginRight, etc.,` is there

Answer (score 0):

put `#003f60` instead of `003f60` because you must put `#` before the property like below

```
$("#tdTopMenu").css({ "background-Color": "#003f60", "height": "17pt", "display": "block", "white-space": "nowrap", "min-width": "1250px" });
```